# PowerShell - find-replace multiple strings with Unicode characters in a file

Tags: powershell, replace, unicode

i am trying to replace multiple strings in a file in powershell, but with a unicode equivalents

e.g.

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{'Out-File:Encoding' = 'utf8'}
$fileContent = Get-Content "D:\PS\comp.txt"
$updatedContent = $fileContent -replace 'EU','EU-01' -replace 'AP','AP-01'
$updatedContent | Set-Content "D:\PS\comp.txt"
```

In the example the replace operator replaces the "EU" and "AP" with the "EU-01" and "AP-01".

I need to replace some country stings names i.e. "UK", "Ireland'', "France" etc, with their unicode equivalents.

i.e.

```
$updatedContent = $fileContent -replace 'Ireland','IE' -replace 'UK','GB'
```

Where:

"IE" should be Unicode U+1F1EE U+1F1EA (i.e )

"GB" should be Unicode U+1F1EC U+1F1E7 (i.e )

I am unsure how to get this part in a powershell.
Thank you.

Comment: It should work, but a powershell 5.1 script has to be encoded in utf8 with bom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?  Both the script itself and the output file have to be utf8 *with bom*.  Out-File's defaults don't apply here.  Might want to backup the file first.  In Powershell 7, everything is utf8 no bom by default.

```
$fileContent = Get-Content D:\PS\comp.txt
$updatedContent = $fileContent -replace 'EU','EU-01' -replace 'AP',
  'AP-01' -replace 'Ireland','' -replace 'UK',''
$updatedContent | Set-Content D:\PS\comp.txt -encoding utf8
```

Or a one-liner, the parentheses serve to completely run get-content first.

```
(Get-Content D:\PS\comp.txt) -replace 'EU','EU-01' -replace 'AP',
  'AP-01' -replace 'Ireland','' -replace 'UK','' | 
  Set-Content D:\PS\comp.txt -encoding utf8
```

utf8 bom:

```
get-content -encoding byte -totalcount 3 file | % tostring x

ef
bb
bf
```

Comment: Yes, that was it. All that was needed was to append "-encoding utf8".
Thanks for the tip.